# Bootstrap select dropdown only the Icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

```js
$('.search-panel .dropdown-menu').find('a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var concept = $(this).text();
  $('.search-panel span#search_concept').text(concept);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-btn search-panel">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <span id="search_concept"></span> <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-th" aria-hidden="true"></i> All Category</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-laptop" aria-hidden="true"></i> IT Solutions</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-paint-brush" aria-hidden="true"></i> Design &amp; Multimedia</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i> Social Media &amp; Marketing</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-graduation-cap" aria-hidden="true"></i> Education &amp; Training</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Writing &amp; Translation</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gavel" aria-hidden="true"></i> Legal Affairs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-money" aria-hidden="true"></i> Finance &amp; Accounting</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-building-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Construction &amp; Architecture</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-credit-card" aria-hidden="true"></i> Sales</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-camera-retro" aria-hidden="true"></i> Photography &amp; Event</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i> Household</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-arrows" aria-hidden="true"></i> Rest of All</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" name="search_param" value="all" id="search_param">         
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="x" placeholder="Enter search keyword here" [(ngModel)] = 'title'>
  <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" (click) = "searchParams(optradio,location,payType,title)" ></span></button>
  </span>
</div>
```

the following code results to the following result. As I click in the drop down the selected item appears in the place of All category but I want only the Icon to the selected dropdown to apper in the place of All category how can that be done ?

[image]

Comment: Just to clarify... you want only the dropdown arrow to show after you have selected a category from the drop down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```js
    $('.search-panel .dropdown-menu').find('a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var concept = $(this).find("i")[0];
  debugger
  $('.search-panel span#search_concept').html(concept);

  });
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="input-group">
                      <div class="input-group-btn search-panel">
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            <span id="search_concept"></span> <span class="caret"></span>
                          </button>
                          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-th" aria-hidden="true"></i> All Category</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-laptop" aria-hidden="true"></i> IT Solutions</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-paint-brush" aria-hidden="true"></i> Design &amp; Multimedia</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i> Social Media &amp; Marketing</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-graduation-cap" aria-hidden="true"></i> Education &amp; Training</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Writing &amp; Translation</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gavel" aria-hidden="true"></i> Legal Affairs</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-money" aria-hidden="true"></i> Finance &amp; Accounting</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-building-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Construction &amp; Architecture</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-credit-card" aria-hidden="true"></i> Sales</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-camera-retro" aria-hidden="true"></i> Photography &amp; Event</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i> Household</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-arrows" aria-hidden="true"></i> Rest of All</a></li>
                          </ul>
                      </div>
                      <input type="hidden" name="search_param" value="all" id="search_param">         
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="x" placeholder="Enter search keyword here" [(ngModel)] = 'title'>
                      <span class="input-group-btn">
                          <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" (click) = "searchParams(optradio,location,payType,title)" ></span></button>
                      </span>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you wanted t use bootstrap select so I thought I might suggest you something which won't even require you to write any `javascript`, you should use `data-content` or `data-icon` attribute provided by bootstrap select, depending on if you want to show text with icon or icon only see here for [examples](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/#styling), in the demo below I have used `glyphicon` you can use font awesome or any other you like.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/css/bootstrap-select.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/i18n/defaults-en_US.js"></script>

<select class="selectpicker">
    <option data-icon="glyphicon-glass">Mustard</option>
    <option data-icon="glyphicon-heart">Ketchup</option>
    <option data-icon="glyphicon-film">Relish</option>
    <option data-icon="glyphicon-home">Mayonnaise</option>
    <option data-icon="glyphicon-print">Barbecue Sauce</option>
  </select>

<select class="selectpicker">
    <option data-content="<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-glass'></i>">Mustard</option>
    <option data-content="<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-heart'></i>">Ketchup</option>
    <option data-content="<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-film'></i>">Relish</option>
    <option data-content="<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-home'></i>">Mayonnaise</option>
    <option data-content="<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-print'></i>">Barbecue Sauce</option>
  </select>
```